# Task count for completed tasks

Tags: ms-project-2013

I need to know how many tasks are 100% complete in my project.  How do I get a current total of the number of tasks that are 100% complete from my %Complete column?

Answer (score 2):

Add a spare number field (Number1 for example) and customize the field with the following formula:

**IIf([% complete]=100,1,0)**

In the Custom fields dialog under "*Calculation for task and group summary rows*" select "*Sum*" in the Rollup drop down.

Turn on the Project Summary task to see a total count of complete tasks.